Create a selector in TreeView format
I have a custom screen, with TreeView format as shown in screenshot 1, I would like to create a selector on the Stock Items, attribute tab which shows the values in a TreeView like screenshot 2. How can I create a TreeView selector?
Screenshot 1:

Screenshot 2:

